# No Wifi selection Ubuntu 22.04 on Broadcom 4360 (Macbook Air 2015)

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, macbook

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS using a Live USB on to my Macbook air from 2015 (in ubuntu hardware model reads "Apple inc.MacbookAir7,2"

Upon successful installation I noticed I couldn't access anything involving wifi. Thru my research I found that it is most likely is the wifi card though I am unsure.

I am unable to connect to wifi or hardwire an internet connection without purchasing the proper ethernet adapter for mac. **Which I am willing to do if it can resolve the issue**. However I wont be able to provide data that appears thru command line (at least not as detailed) here since I am posting on a different machine.

In other posts looking to resolve the same/similar issue it has been suggested to use a thumb drive between to different devices to install a driver. However they were rather outdated and were running on ubuntu 15.

Update:
when running the  `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`
command it says I have a BCM4360 802.11ac [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)

kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

Comment: Can you tether your phone temporarily? Please edit your question to tell us what Broadcom you have from the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I have updated my post with the the broadcom info. No I need a firewire cable to connect a device or ethernet cable to my computer.(Unless this can be done thru usb) I am willing to buy one if it will make this process any easier. If I hard wire an ethernet will i have immediate internet access? or will i need to do anything further?

Answer (score 0):

(I am new to askubuntu so suggestions are welcome).
I have a similar situation with my Ubuntu 22 not finding the Broadcom Wifi adapter on a 2014 Toshiba Satellite S70t-B.  I did hard wire to my T-mobile modem and was immediately connected.  The settings for network give a clue mentioning wire or cable (I'm on a Lenovo laptop now and the Wifi for Ubuntu works fine on this running off the USB.)

Comment: Nice! I have connect my phone as a USB modem and can now access the internet. I have downloaded the drivers using ```sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer``` and ```sudo apt install linux-firmware``` as suggested in this post, thought im not to sure it will fix my problem, it may work for you 
  https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Comment: That's the incorrect driver. Please try the driver recommended at the duplicate: `bcmwl-kernel-source`

Comment: @Chilli555 resolved! Thank you Im excited to use Ubuntu 22!!

Comment: The solution to my Wifi connection problem was that i needed to disable secure boot because the Broadcomn driver i am using is unsigned.  Once i did that it is working very well (though not tested for speed).